# Oracle execution plan differs if using partition extended syntax

Tags: oracle, partitioning, sql-execution-plan

I am querying in Oracle 12c a large subpartitioned table which has statistics on the table and partition level but nothing gathered on the subpartition level. I get notably different explain plan results for different partition syntax, presumably because one of these relies on the nonexistent subpartition statistics...? And I've confirmed with gather_plan_statistics / dbms_xplan.display_cursor that the actual execution matches the plans, and since one of these plans uses hash joins and the other nested loops, I'm seeing measurably different performance on these queries.

(It's not just this particular production table, either. I can reproduce the plan difference with a test list-range subpartitioned table, a test indexed lookup table, a handful of records, and 'global and partition' dbms_stats.)

Query 1 with extended partition syntax:

```
select distinct lkt.txt_other
from subpart_test partition(p_2) spt
left join lookup_test lkt on spt.num_other = lkt.num_other
where spt.dt_subkey > to_date('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

This gives me an execution plan with a cardinality of 1 for my subpartitioned table; presumably because of that, it uses a nested loop join. Against a production table partition with an actual row count of 55M, this averages just under 6 minutes to run.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |               |     1 |    17 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                          |               |     1 |    17 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                  |               |     1 |    17 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE              |               |     1 |    11 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR          |               |     1 |    11 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     6 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                | SUBPART_TEST  |     1 |    11 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |     7 |    12 |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| LOOKUP_TEST   |     2 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  7 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I_LOOKUP_TEST |     2 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Query 2 with the partition key in the where clause:

```
select distinct lkt.txt_other
from subpart_test spt
left join lookup_test lkt on spt.num_other = lkt.num_other
where spt.dt_subkey > to_date('20140101', 'YYYYMMDD')
and spt.num_key = 2
```

This gives me an execution plan with accurate row count estimates; this leads to a hash join. Against the same production table, this averages just under 4 minutes to run. (Is this a 2 minute improvement or a 33% improvement? Only testing against one of the larger partitions will tell for sure, and that will obviously take longer to do.)

This is also the execution plan I get for query 1 if I generate statistics for the subpartitions on my test table (I can't try this in production) but not if I include the partition key in the where clause for a partition specification double whammy: just having the partition() syntax without those subpartition stats messes with the cardinality estimation no matter what else I do.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |              |     8 |   160 |    13   (8)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE                |              |     8 |   160 |    13   (8)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER           |              |    17 |   340 |    12   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|   3 |    PARTITION LIST SINGLE    |              |    10 |   140 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |     2 |     2 |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|              |    10 |   140 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |     3 |     6 |
|*  5 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL      | SUBPART_TEST |    10 |   140 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |     7 |    12 |
|   6 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | LOOKUP_TEST  |    30 |   180 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Anybody know what's going on and how I can best work on performance tuning against tables with no statistics on their subpartitions? It's not just this one table; I have a lot of tables like it to work with on the same pattern of "query a single partition and within that a range of several subpartitions while joining to some other tables". At the moment I'm thinking a mixed strategy of "ask my DBA what's up with the subpartition stats" and "put hash join and index hints on everything for the next round of performance testing"....

Comment: Just to double check; you have no stats on your sub-partitions; not stats that say no rows.?

Comment: Also it looks like you are partitioning by list(num_key), sub-partition by range( dt_subkey). Is that correct?

Comment: Do you have dynamic sampling disabled by chance?

Comment: @BobC Yes, that's correct. Last analyzed, num rows, blocks are all null.

Comment: When you do a query that prunes to >1 partition, Oracle uses the global stats. That would explain q2. However, I am wondering that by using the partition extended syntax, if essentially "see's" a table with no stats? In that case though, I would expect dynamic sampling to kick in, hence my last question...

Comment: @BobC Yes, those are the partition/subpartition keys on my test table. I'm not familiar with dynamic sampling, although a quick Google on the subject looks promising -- how can I tell if it's disabled?

Comment: It might be set system wide - check the value of optimizer_dynamic_sampling (the default is 2). It can also be changed within a session. Having said that, I am not (yet) suggesting that this is the fix; I'm looking at root cause. Incidentally, it looks like you have created a simple test case - would it be possible for you to send me you DDL/data?

Comment: Why not just use the second syntax? The table is list partitioned so why would you specify the partition name directly? But, your subpartitions should have stats. Get on your DBA. :)

Comment: @BobC It looks like it was set to 0; I tried setting it to 4 and my sample table did produce a plan with the right estimates and a hash join, but my (slightly more complicated) production query did not, even if I set the level to 10. I'd be happy to send you my sample table -- what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Can you email it to me? Bob.carlin@oracle.com

Comment: @BobC Will do. Thank you!